# Drawing images (in p5.js) based on PoseNet

Tags: javascript, p5.js, ml5.js

I am using ml5's poseNet in the p5.js web editor to place a funky head image on the face of a user using the webcam. I would like the sketch to draw a warning sign (the image *'warning1.png'* in the sketch files) when there is no one in the frame. The sketch can already log **'no one in the frame'** when it detects 0 poses, but how can I draw the image *warning1.png* over the canvas when it's not written in the draw function but in the setup function?

```
if (poses.length == 0) {
    console.log('no one in the frame')
  }
```

Same story goes for when there is more than one person in the frame (I am using poseNet's multiPose). The sketch detects +1 person in the frame (and the console logs **'too many people in the frame'**)...

```
if (poses.length > 1) {
      console.log('too many people in the frame')
  }
```

... but how do I draw the image *'warning2.png'* over the canvas.

Also, I would like the *funkyhead.png* image to disappear when one of the above situations occur — now the image is **always** drawn. Here's my sketch in the p5.js web editor:
https://editor.p5js.org/saskiasmith/sketches/_5O_aAzE_

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create another global variable to keep track of whether the error is currently occuring or not. In `gotPoses` you can add an else statement to your if statement. And then you set your global variable true or false. In `draw` you use that same global variable to determine whether to show the image or not.

So:
`let noPoseDetected = false;`

in getPoses:

```
if (poses.length == 0) {
    console.log('no one in the frame');
    noPoseDetected = true;
  } else {
    noPoseDetected = false;
  }
```

And then in draw:

```
if (noPoseDetected) {
    image(warning1, 0, 0, 50,50);
}
```

That shoud work for all your use cases.